# Was the first T-800 sent from Europe?

Tags: the-terminator-series

Was the first T-800 sent from a Europen country? I understand why all the later versions of the Arnold model sounded like the first one. But why did the first one have a thick accent? The T2 version of Arnold was able to sound like young John Connor when he spoke in the phone booth, and the bad Terminators in T2 and T3 mimic other voices. Was the first T-800 damaged and unable to adapt his voice once he arrived? Is there a canon reason why the first one didn't adopt an American accent to blend in?

Comment: In T1 the terminator sounded like Sarah Conner's mother and a police officer.  They seem to be able to copy any voice they have heard perfectly even if they have not heard the exact words they are going to use.  When copying Sarah's mother he even used frantic intonations etc without arousing Sarah's suspition.  Also, consider that skynet had been badly damaged, it is unlikely that it would have had detailed information on a 20th century American accent or any other.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A deleted scene from T3 actually explained it.

The scene showed a promotional video from the military R&D showing the development of the new type of battlefield humanoid robots; and the humanoid model was based off of Chief Master Sergeant William Candy (played by you can guess who).

[image]

[image]

The military brass hated the sergeant's "ya'll" Southern accent, and a military scientist with a deep Austrian accent (played by you can guess who) present at the debriefing said "we can fix it [voice]".

[image]

The rest is a (deleted) history.

Comment: That's funny. Pretty poor infiltration unit programing though.

Comment: @MajorStacking true, but one of my favourite bits of the film!

Comment: It's not so poor if you understand the original specifications. It'd only have to pass for human long enough to get within rifle range of the enemy. If you're close enough to be suspicious of the accent, you've already been squashed by an unstoppable killing machine.